# Having error when trying to use 'From' clause in an 'Update' statement in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm pretty new to SQL so sorry if this is a dumb question.

I have a large table containing most of the counties from every state with a median home listing price. Each county/state has multiple observations because it has a new observation for every quarter for the past five years. I'm trying to create a new column that has the percentage change in median listing price from the previous quarter.
mySQL says that I have a syntax error, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
UPDATE housing AS current
    SET price_change =((current.medListingPrice - previous.prevMLP)/ previous.prevMLP)*100
FROM
    (SELECT
        county,
        state,
        year,
        quarter,
        medListingPrice,
        LAG(medListingPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY county, state ORDER BY year, quarter) AS prevMLP
    FROM housing) AS previous
    WHERE current.county = previous.county
        AND current.state = previous.state
        AND current.quarter = previous.quarter
        AND current.year = previous.year;
```

Comment: try this: `UPDATE housing AS current
    SET price_change =( SELECT (((current.medListingPrice - previous.(LAG(medListingPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY county, state ORDER BY year, quarter)))/ previous.(LAG(medListingPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY county, state ORDER BY year, quarter)))*100) FROM housing AS previous WHERE current.county = previous.county
        AND current.state = previous.state
        AND current.quarter = previous.quarter
        AND current.year = previous.year);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE housing AS current
JOIN (
    SELECT
        id,
        county,
        state,
        year,
        quarter,
        medListingPrice,
        LAG(medListingPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY county, state ORDER BY year, quarter) AS prevMLP
    FROM housing
) AS previous ON current.id = previous.id  -- Replace 'id' with the unique identifier column
SET current.price_change = ((current.medListingPrice - previous.prevMLP) / previous.prevMLP) * 100;
```

UPDATE statement in MySQL doesn't support the FROM clause directly
so I use a subquery with the useful data

Answer (score -1):

Your SQL query looks mostly correct, but there's a small mistake in the `UPDATE` statement's syntax. In MySQL, the `UPDATE` statement doesn't use a `FROM` clause like some other SQL databases do. Instead, you can achieve what you want using a subquery in the `SET` clause directly. Here's the modified query:

```sql
UPDATE housing AS current
SET current.price_change = ((current.medListingPrice - previous.prevMLP) / previous.prevMLP) * 100
WHERE (current.year, current.quarter) = (previous.year, previous.quarter)
    AND current.county = previous.county
    AND current.state = previous.state;
```

In this modified version, we directly use a subquery in the `SET` clause to calculate the `price_change`. The subquery you had previously used in the `FROM` clause is not necessary.

Also, note that I replaced the condition `current.year = previous.year` with `(current.year, current.quarter) = (previous.year, previous.quarter)`. This is because you are looking to calculate the percentage change based on the previous quarter's median listing price, and for that, you need to match both the year and quarter to get the correct previous value.

With this modification, your query should work as expected in MySQL.

Comment: This query is all kinds of wrong! You are referencing `previous` but have no table or alias named `previous`.